# unbind/bind not working

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("li::nth-child(1)").click(function () {
      $("li").unbind('click');
       $(".content").fadeIn('slow');
       if ($("#what_image").is(':visible')) {
        $("#what_image").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("#what_text").fadeIn('slow'), function() {
          $("li").bind('click');
          ...
```

The unbind works...All "li" menu elements are disabled for clicking.
When the animation stops i like to bind back all the "li" elements.
To no avail...Something must be wrong cos i cannot rebind the elements...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").bind('click');
```

That line isn't telling it what to do on click. You need to bind it to the function that you want it to perform.

Assuming you want to bind it back to what it was doing before you would want this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function FadeLi() {
      $("li").unbind('click');
      $(".content").fadeIn('slow');
      if ($("#what_image").is(':visible')) {
          $("#what_image").fadeOut('slow', function() {
              $("#what_text").fadeIn('slow'), function() {
                 $("li").bind('click', FadeLi); // Binding to the same function
              }
          }
      }
   }

   $("li::nth-child(1)").click(FadeLi);       
}
```

Comment: I want to unbind it during the animation and that works.
After that I want it to bind back to the initial function being
'$("li::nth-child(1)").click(function ()' 
But how do you have to do that?

Comment: Found it...Thanks to your help.
I used the index of the "li" element"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function clickHandler() {
    $("li").unbind('click');
    $(".content").fadeIn('slow');
    if ($("#what_image").is(':visible')) {
      $("#what_image").fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $("#what_text").fadeIn('slow'), function() {
        $("li").bind('click', clickHandler);
        ...
  }
  $("li::nth-child(1)").click(clickHandler);
```

But I have a feeling that there's a better way to accomplish what you want to than binding and unbinding the events.

Comment: Thanks to both of you...works great...But
the problem is that I have several menu items.
So when one gets clicked it gets unbind and bind.
Of course...the other "li" elements remain unbind...
Using $("li::nth-child(1)").bind('click', FadeLi);...

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I found it thanks to your help!!!

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 function FadeLi() {                                                                
   $("li").unbind('click');                                                         
        var index = $("li").index(this);                                            

         switch(index)                                                              
             {  case 0:                                                             
                    $("#what_image").fadeOut('slow', function() {                   
                    $("#what_text").fadeIn('slow', function() {                     
                    $("li").bind('click', FadeLi); // Binding to the same function  
                       });                                                          
                    });                                                             
                break                                                               
                case 1:                                                             
                     $("#when_image").fadeOut('slow', function() {                  
                     $("#when_text").fadeIn('slow', function() {                    
                     $("li").bind('click', FadeLi); // Binding to the same function 
                        });                                                         
                     });                                                            

                break      
                .
                .
                .
```

Comment: Instead of repeatedly binding & unbinding event handlers during an animation, why don't you just write your event handler so that it ignores clicks during the animation?